# Need help to adjust a Zoom system in Graphics2D - Java

Tags: java, swing, zooming, scale, graphics2d

This is my 1st question here. I'm trying to build a White Page adjustable by zoom. It's inside a JScrollPane, so the size of the JScrollPane's ScrollBars are adjustable in the Dimension of that JPanel.

I want to adjust the size of those ScrollBars as the Size of the page (variables width and height in the code) + 2 borderSize, so the full size is equal the Page + margin of a borderSize around it. It works if zoom = 1.0.

If zoom < 1.0, the scroll bar is smaller than the Page and cut a piece of it. If zoom > 1 the Dimension size is way bigger than the page, leaving a huger border on its right and down corners, bigger than the borderSize.

How do I do this?

PS: I'm started learning java by myself, in the Quarantine last year, never had a teacher, just the internet, so any critics or suggestions, please, tell me.

Here's the JPanel's code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main2 {
private MyPanel mp = new MyPanel();
private JFrame frame;
private JSlider zoomSlider = new JSlider();
private JLabel zoomLabel = new JLabel("Zoom: XXX");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main2 window = new Main2();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public Main2() {
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 619, 403);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);
    
    
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, zoomSlider, 40, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, zoomSlider, -115, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
    zoomSlider.setValue(100);
    zoomSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
    zoomSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    zoomSlider.setMaximum(200);
    zoomSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    zoomSlider.setMinimum(5);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, zoomSlider, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, zoomSlider, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, frame.getContentPane());
    frame.getContentPane().add(zoomSlider);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mp);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, scrollPane, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, zoomSlider);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, scrollPane, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, frame.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, scrollPane, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frame.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, scrollPane, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    
    
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, zoomLabel, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, zoomLabel, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, zoomSlider);
    frame.getContentPane().add(zoomLabel);
    
    
    frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.draw();
        }
        
    });
    
    
    zoomSlider.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int temp = (zoomSlider.getValue())-zoomSlider.getValue()%5;
            setZoom(temp);
            
            mp.draw();
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            int temp = (zoomSlider.getValue())-zoomSlider.getValue()%5;
            setZoom(temp);
            
            
            mp.draw();
        
            
        }
        
        
        
    });
    
    mp.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            if (e.getPreciseWheelRotation() < 0) {
                
                setZoom(zoomSlider.getValue()- 5);
           
            } else {
                setZoom(zoomSlider.getValue()+ 5);
            }
        // zoom += e.getPreciseWheelRotation();
            if (mp.getZoom()*100 < 10) {
                setZoom(10);
            }
            mp.draw();
        }
        });
    
    AdjustmentListener adj = new AdjustmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            setZoom(zoomSlider.getValue());
            mp.draw();
            
        }
        
    };
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(adj);
    scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(adj);
    
    
}
public void setZoom(int n) {
    mp.setZoom(n);
    zoomSlider.setValue(n);
    zoomLabel.setText("Zoom: "+mp.getZoom()+"x");
    
}
}
class MyPanel extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -716735372803790424L;

int borderSize=28;
int zoom=100;
int height = 3565;
int width = 2537;
int widthz, heightz; 

public MyPanel() {
setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
int a, b;
String temp;
Float x, y;
x=(getZoom()*width); //Size of the page adjusted by zoom
y=(getZoom()*height);

temp = x.toString(); 
String temp1[] = temp.split("\\."); // converted to string to convert it to int
a = Integer.valueOf(temp1[0])+2*borderSize; //that value + 2 BorderSize
temp = y.toString();
String temp2[] = temp.split("\\.");
b = Integer.valueOf(temp2[0])+2*borderSize;

return new Dimension (a,b);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g2d = putZoom(g2d);
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2d.fillRect(this.getX(),this.getY(), width, height);
g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2d.drawRect(this.getX()+borderSize,this.getY()+borderSize,width-2*borderSize,height-2*borderSize);
g2d.dispose();

}

public Graphics2D putZoom(Graphics2D g) {

AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(borderSize,borderSize); // put the page a borderSize from the upper-left corner
at.scale(getZoom(),getZoom()); //adjust the page as zoom 

Graphics2D g2d = g;
g2d.setTransform(at);
return g2d;
}

public void draw() { //this method is to update the draw from the main
repaint();

}

public Float getZoom() {
return Float.valueOf(zoom)/100;
}
public void setZoom(int zom) { //this method is to update Zoom from the main

zoom=zom;
String zoomheight []= (String.valueOf(getZoom()*height)).split("\\.");
heightz = Integer.valueOf(zoomheight[0]);
String zoomwidth []= (String.valueOf(getZoom()*width)).split("\\.");
widthz = Integer.valueOf(zoomwidth[0]);

}

public int getZoomInt() {
return this.zoom;
}

}
```

Zoom(values from 0.1 to 2.0).

How can i improve this?  Also, i have no idea how to update the JScrollPane's scrollbars together with the zoom.Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:** i've created a minimal reproducible exemple.

Comment: What do you want to happen to your GUI when the zoom is larger than 1.0?  Without a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE and play around with, and without knowing what you want your zoom function to do, it's hard to provide any help.  Since you're new to Java and Swing, I recommend that you review the Oracle [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally did it. Started by not using transformation for scaling it, but making a new draw with the size zoomed, adapting all sizes in the method setSizes(), and adjusting the Dimension by those sizes.
(Just changed this class)

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -716735372803790424L;

int borderSize=28;
int zoom=100;
int height = 3565;
int width = 2537;
int widthz, heightz;
int maxHeight, maxWidth; //max size of draw
int maxAreaHeight, maxAreaWidth; //max size of area

public MyPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    setSizes();
    return new Dimension (maxAreaWidth,maxAreaHeight);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d= createBase(g2d);

}

public void draw() { //this method is to update the draw from the main
    repaint();

}

public Float getZoom() {return Float.valueOf(zoom)/100;}
public void setZoom(int zom) {zoom=zom;}
public int getZoomInt() {return this.zoom;}

public void setSizes () {
    widthz= width*getZoomInt()/100;
    heightz=height*getZoomInt()/100;
    maxHeight = heightz+2*borderSize;
    maxWidth = widthz +2*borderSize;
    maxAreaHeight = this.getY()+maxHeight;
    maxAreaWidth = this.getX()+maxWidth;

    if (this.getSize() != new Dimension(maxAreaWidth, maxAreaHeight)) {
        this.setSize(maxAreaWidth, maxAreaHeight);
    }
}
public Graphics2D createBase(Graphics2D g2d) {
    Graphics2D g = g2d;
    setSizes();

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(this.getX()+borderSize,this.getY()+borderSize, widthz, heightz);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(this.getX()+borderSize+borderSize*zoom/100,this.getY()+borderSize+borderSize*zoom/100,widthz-2*borderSize*zoom/100,heightz-2*borderSize*zoom/100);


    return g;
}

}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

I started working on this before you updated your question.  I used a zoom percentage rather than a zoom factor.

I created the following GUI and set the initial state to 30 percent.

[image: Zoom JPanel 1]

I made the inner `JPanel` a checkerboard so you can more easily see the zoom.  I modified your initial values so the inner `JPanel` would represent an 8 1/2 x 11 piece of paper at 50 pixels per inch.

Here's the same GUI at 100 percent.

[image: Zoom JPanel 2]

Here's the same GUI at 10 percent.

[image: Zoom JPanel 3]

## Explanation

I created a `JFrame` and a control `JPanel` to hold the `JSlider`.  I used a `GridLayout` to create the control `JPanel`.

I created an inner `JPanel` to hold the drawing and a display `JPanel` that holds the `JScrollPane`.  I made the display `JPanel` proportionate to the size of the inner `JPanel` so I wouldn't have any stretching issues.

Getting the GUI to revalidate / repaint turned out to be the biggest challenge.  I wound up having to `invalidate` the `JScrollPane`, both `JScrollBars`, and the display `JPanel`.  I also had to reset the `JScrollBars` to zero each time I changed the zoom percentage.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all of the classes inner classes so I could post this as one code block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ZoomJPanelGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ZoomJPanelGUI());
    }
    
    private int zoomPercentage = 30;
    
    private DisplayPanel displayPanel;
    
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Zoom JPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        this.displayPanel = new DisplayPanel(zoomPercentage);
        frame.add(displayPanel.getPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 15, 5, 15));
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Zoom Percentage");
        label.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
        panel.add(label);
        
        JSlider slider =  new JSlider(
                JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 10, 100, zoomPercentage);
        slider.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(16f));
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(30);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
                JSlider slider = (JSlider) event.getSource();
                if (!slider.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    zoomPercentage = (int) slider.getValue();
                    displayPanel.setZoomPercentage(zoomPercentage);
                    displayPanel.repaint();
                    frame.pack();
                }
            }   
        });
        
        panel.add(slider);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class DisplayPanel {
        
        private InnerPanel innerPanel;
        
        private final JPanel panel;
        
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        
        private int zoomPercentage;
        
        public DisplayPanel(int zoomPercentage) {
            this.zoomPercentage = zoomPercentage;
            this.panel = createDisplayPanel();
        }

        private JPanel createDisplayPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            
            this.innerPanel = new InnerPanel(zoomPercentage);
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(475, 600));
            panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            
            return panel;
        }
        
        public void setZoomPercentage(int zoomPercentage) {
            this.zoomPercentage = zoomPercentage;
            innerPanel.setZoomPercentage(zoomPercentage);
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }

        public void repaint() {
            innerPanel.repaint();
            scrollPane.invalidate();
            JScrollBar hScrollBar = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
            JScrollBar vScrollBar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            hScrollBar.setValue(0);
            vScrollBar.setValue(0);
            hScrollBar.invalidate();
            vScrollBar.invalidate();
            panel.invalidate();
        }
        
    }
    
    public class InnerPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private int maximumBorderSize = 25;
        private int maximumCellSize = 50;
        private int maximumHeight = 5500;
        private int maximumWidth = 4250;
        private int zoomPercentage;
        
        public InnerPanel(int zoomPercentage) {
            this.zoomPercentage = zoomPercentage;
        }
        
        public void setZoomPercentage(int zoomPercentage) {
            this.zoomPercentage = zoomPercentage;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            int width = maximumWidth * zoomPercentage / 100;
            int height = maximumHeight * zoomPercentage / 100;
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            
            int borderSize = maximumBorderSize * zoomPercentage / 100;
            paintBackground(g2d);
            paintBorder(g2d, borderSize);
            paintCheckerboard(g2d, borderSize);
        }

        private void paintBackground(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        private void paintBorder(Graphics2D g2d, int borderSize) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
            g2d.drawRect(borderSize, borderSize, getWidth() - 2 * borderSize,
                    getHeight() - 2 * borderSize);
        }

        private void paintCheckerboard(Graphics2D g2d, int borderSize) {
            int cellSize = maximumCellSize * zoomPercentage / 100;
            int width = maximumWidth - maximumBorderSize * 2 - 2;
            int height = maximumHeight - maximumBorderSize * 2 - 2;
            int cellWidth = width / maximumCellSize;
            int cellHeight = height / maximumCellSize;
            
            boolean isBlue = true;
            int x = borderSize;
            int y = borderSize;
            int heightRemainder = height - cellHeight * cellSize;
            for (int i = 0; i < cellHeight; i++) {
                int widthRemainder = width - cellWidth * cellSize;
                for (int j = 0; j < cellWidth; j++) {
                    if (isBlue) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    } else {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }
                    isBlue = !isBlue;
                    g2d.fillRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize);
                    x += cellSize;
                    if (widthRemainder > 0) {
                        x++;
                        widthRemainder--;
                    }
                }
//              isBlue = !isBlue;
                x = borderSize;
                y += cellSize;
                if (heightRemainder > 0) {
                    y++;
                    heightRemainder--;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I really liked your code, i'm learning a lot from it, and gonna read it more, thanks a lot for it, but it still having the same problem. If zoomPercentage < 100% (Or 1.0 in mine) the scrollbar cuts the checkerboard (See how the checkboard go beyond your created black border), and if u use zoomPercentagem > 100%, by extending the slider, the checkboard will be smaller than the scrollbar and the border.

Comment: @Yuri Pinto: Yep.  No matter how you zoom, you have to deal with fractional pixels.  I deliberately kept the zoom limits between 10 and 100 percent for the reasons you outlined.