# Zoom to Point with JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I found a few questions similar to the one I have, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471300/jscrollpane-and-zooming-images), but none that really answered the problem, and it's because I am using a `JScrollPane`. I found the code necessary for the formula; it's this:

```
originX -= mouseX / zoom - mouseX;
originY -= mouseY / zoom - mouseY;
```

So I tried plugging it into a `JScrollPane`:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = drawFrame.scrollPane;
JScrollBar vert = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar(),
      horiz = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
horiz.setValue(
     (int)(horiz.getValue() - (float)pastMouseX / zoom + pastMouseX)
);
vert.setValue(
     (int)(vert.getValue() - (float)pastMouseY / zoom + pastMouseY)
);
```

And the point at which the mouse zooms into is all over the place and I don't know why. Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class ResizeTest extends JFrame{
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    BufferedImage image;
    int mouseX, mouseY;
    float zoom;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new ResizeTest();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public ResizeTest(){
        zoom = 1;
        
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("a.jpg"));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2.scale(zoom, zoom);
                g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                System.out.println(zoom);
            }
            
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            }
            
        };
        
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        
        panel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                if(e.isControlDown()) {
                    if(e.getWheelRotation() > 0){
                        zoom /= 1.3333333333f;
                        if(zoom < 0.125)
                           zoom = 0.125f;
                    }
                    else if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0){
                        zoom *= 1.3333333333f;
                        if(zoom > 10)
                            zoom = 10;
                    }
                    if(zoom < 10){
                        JScrollBar vert = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar(),
                                horiz = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
                        horiz.setValue(
                                (int)(horiz.getValue() - (float)mouseX / zoom + mouseX)
                        );
                        vert.setValue(
                                (int)(vert.getValue() - (float)mouseY / zoom + mouseY)
                        );
                    }

                } else {
                    scrollPane.dispatchEvent(e);
                }
                
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseX = e.getX();
                mouseY = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseX = e.getX();
                mouseY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        
        setSize(new Dimension(1200,700));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(scrollPane);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(1200, 700);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Make your zoom an `int` scale from 10 to 100 in 10 steps.  2) Draw or read your image at its maximum size.  3) Always reduce your maximum image down by the scale value.  4) Your origin formulas zoom in and out on the origin (upper left corner) of the image.  Most people want to zoom based on the mouse pointer.  You have to calculate the image size at each scale factor and figure out how to move the `JScrollPane` sliders so the mouse pointer point remains in the center of the `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Check out these two Stack Overflow answers: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871001/need-help-to-adjust-a-zoom-system-in-graphics2d-java/66876004#66876004), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963087/can-someone-explain-the-formula-parameters-needed-to-set-a-view-relative-to-th/74963570#74963570).

Comment: Neither of those are quite what I'm looking for. The problem is somewhere in the ```JScrollPane``` and how it takes in the new scrolling coordinates with the formula I found on other questions.

Comment: Does anybody know where exactly in the ```JScrollBar``` that ```getValue()``` returns? Is it on the very left or right side of where the scrolling bar is on the ```JScrollBar```'s total length?

Comment: "Where it returns" doesn't make sense, unless you're asking about a change listener or other state listener. *What* it returns is the relative location of the viewport view within the viewport.

Comment: Scrolling works when the preferred size of the component in the scroll pane is greater than the size of the scroll pane. Don't hardcode the preferred size. Instead the size should be dynamically calculated based on the size of the image and the zoom factor.

Comment: What I'm asking is what ```getValue()``` really returns, as in, whether it returns the value on the left end of the bar in the ```JScrollBar```, the center, or the right end of it (I don't mean the left, right or center of the entire ```JScrollBar```).